# Google Sheets How to multiply two cells then add that value to a different cell all in one

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[image: sheet example]

Basically what i want to do is

(D4*E4)+F4.  I want this sum in G4

So in my example 100*8= 800  800+1=801. But obviously i want to auto-populate G4

Comment: it sure seems like you have the formula to put into G4 already. Did you mean to ask "How do I write a formula in a cell?"

=(D4*E4)+F4

Comment: correct that is what i need

Comment: You literally just write it

Answer (score 1):

use this in G3:

```
={"Gold Allocated to order"; INDEX(IF(C4:C="";;(D4:D*E4:E)+F4:F))}
```